# Psalm Cannot find referenced variable $articles in global scope в шаблоне подключенном через include

Tags: php, статический-анализ, static-analysis, psalm

Работаю над добавлением Psalm в проект. В нем есть метод-функция для подключения php файла-шаблона:

```php
public function include(string $template, array $args = array(), bool $echo = true)
{
    include $this->templates_path . $template;
}
```

С ее помощью подключается шаблон arcticles.php:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

/**
 * @var Article[] $articles
 */

foreach ($articles as $article) :
//...
endforeach;
```

Статический анализ в PHP Storm правильно связывает с $articles с типом Article, но psalm выдает ошибку `Cannot find referenced variable $articles in global scope`

Как можно доработать psalm, чтобы он воспринимал переменную с @var как переменную переданную в шаблон?